# Rerender Typeahead Custom Component

Tags: visualforce-component, rerender, actionsupport, onchange

I am using below Typeahead Component to search for existing Contacts in visualforce page. But when I rerender section of Typeahead component it is showing blank page.

https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/visualforce-typeahead

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" id="page" tabStyle="Account">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Industry}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="SectionID1,SectionID2"/>
          </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:outputPanel id="SectionID1" >
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Account.Industry== 'Agriculture',True,False)}">
           <c:typeahead/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      <apex:outputPanel id="SectionID2" >
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Account.Industry== 'Banking',True,False)}">
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="SectionB" columns="2" >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >ITEM 1</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >ITEM 2</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >ITEM 3</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [component](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/visualforce-typeahead/blob/master/src/components/Typeahead.component#L178) sets up the jQuery code using:

```
    j$(document).ready(function(){

        j$('#{!searchBoxId}').typeahead({
            minLength: {!minSearchLength},
            hint: true,
            autoselect: true,
            highlight: true
        },
        ....
```

but that `ready` callback only happens on the initial page load and not when you re-render part of the page.

Two solutions:

- don't re-render
- get the author (or do it yourself) to expose a JavaScript function that you can call from the `oncomplete` of the `apex:actionSupport`; that function should re-apply the jQuery Logic

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually the issue, I've tried this and it doesn't make any difference to the rerender failure - code [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172695/trying-to-rerender-typeahead-component). I did find that commenting out the typeahead library reference (  line 14 - window.typeahead || document.write('<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Typeahead, '/typeahead.bundle.min.js')}"><\/script>');   ) from the component stops the rerender failure from occurring, although obviously it breaks the typeahead functionality. So there might be an issue with this library?